# How mongo index intersection works

Tags: mongodb, mlab

If I create two indexes, one with descending and one with ascending with time, if I query old and new data do I get to search in both the indexes and I get a good performance in both the cases.

Currently I have index in descending so when I query old data it is coming really really slow. I am thinking of creating one more ascending and try it out. Since I have a huge number of documents (32 million) I thought of asking here first.
This is my index and the query which cause me issue when start/end time is bit old. I have a TTL close to 100 days which make my collection to keep 32 million documents.

```
index: { 
    "source_type" : 1.0 , 
    "source_id" : 1.0 , 
    "key" : 1.0 , 
    "start" : -1.0 , 
    "end" : -1.0
} 

query: keys = diag_db.telemetry_series.aggregate([
    { '$match': {
      'source_type': 'SERVER',
      'start': { '$gte': start },
      'end':   { '$lte': end },
      '$or': stream_id_query
    }},
    { '$project': {
      'source_id': 1,
      'key': 1
    }},
    { '$group':
      { '_id': { 'source': '$source_id', 'key': '$key' }
    }}
  ])['result']
```

Comment: All indexes should be able to used in reverse order without any performance loss. Maybe you can tell us more about your indexes and queries?

Comment: Hi Sammaye, Updated the post